# ValueError: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django

is there something wrong with my code? i already run makemigrations and migrate, and i can see the picture i saved on the admin site, but why when i try to call this picture on my html i received this error?

[image]

this is my html

```
{% for perfume in s %}
    <img src="{{perfume.image.url}}" width="192px" height="192px" class="class">
{% endfor %}
```

my views.py

```
s = Perfume.objects.all()
....
```

my models.py

```
class Perfume(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image',null=True, blank=True)
    ....
```

my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

import os

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
def get_success_url(self, request, user):
    return (get_success_url)
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
      ....
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ImageField` declared `blank=True, null=True` so image can be empty. You need to check if image has uploaded in your html.

```
{% for perfume in s %}
    {% if perfume.image %}
        <img src="{{ perfume.image.url }}">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @justin do not forget accept the anwser if it solved your problem.